# Firebase CLI Fails to Authenticate with Github Actions

Tags: firebase, continuous-integration, github-actions, firebase-tools

I have this action for my Next project. The goal is to build and deploy to Firebase using a service account key. If there is a better way, I'm open to that as well.

```yaml
name: Build and Deploy
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
jobs:
  build_and_deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout ️
        uses: actions/checkout@master
        with:
          persist-credentials: false

      - name: Setup Node.js environment ️
        uses: actions/setup-node@master
        with:
          node-version: "16"

      - name: Create SA key
        run: echo '${{ secrets.FIREBASE_SERVICE_ACCOUNT }}' > $GITHUB_WORKSPACE/gcloud.json

      - name: Set SA Key
        run: |
          export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=$GITHUB_WORKSPACE/gcloud.json

      - name: Install Dependencies and Build
        run: |
          npm i
          ./node_modules/.bin/nuxt build

      - name: Deploy
        env:
          GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS: ${{ env.GITHUB_WORKSPACE }}/gcloud.json
        run: |
          node predeploy.mjs
          ./node_modules/.bin/firebase deploy --only hosting,functions:server --json --project website-****-*****
```

However, this is the error I get in the Github logs:

```
{
  "status": "error",
  "error": "Failed to authenticate, have you run \u001b[1mfirebase login\u001b[22m?"
}
```

I already confirmed that the key is in `secrets.FIREBASE_SERVICE_ACCOUNT`.

Comment: Is `FIREBASE_SERVICE_ACCOUNT` a single value or json?

Comment: @KrzysztofMadej json

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this by removing the `--json` flag and saving `gcloud.json` to the current directory.

```yaml
name: Build and Deploy
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
jobs:
  build_and_deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout ️
        uses: actions/checkout@master
        with:
          persist-credentials: false

      - name: Setup Node.js environment ️
        uses: actions/setup-node@master
        with:
          node-version: "19"

      - name: Create SA key
        run: echo '${{ secrets.FIREBASE_SERVICE_ACCOUNT }}' > gcloud.json

      - name: Install Dependencies and Build
        run: |
          npm i
          ./node_modules/.bin/nuxt build

      - name: Predploy
        run: |
          node predeploy.mjs

      - name: Deploy
        env:
          GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS: gcloud.json
        run: |
          npx firebase-tools deploy --only hosting,functions:server --project website-*** --debug
```